# Reset a new button to its old form using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I need some help regarding this reset functionality. Currently I have an image and if I click anywhere in the image I get a popup with a button saying 'Menu'. When this button is clicked upon, a new button comes up saying 'vegetation'. Now I want that if I click anywhere else on the image I see the button saying 'Menu' and not 'vegetation'. Vegetation should only be seen every time if I click upon the button 'Menu'. Any help will be much appreciated. Here is my html code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>its4land</title>

    <style>

    .popup {
        display: inline-block;
        cursor: pointer;
    }


    .popuptext {
        display: none;
        color: black;
        position: absolute;
        top: 100px;
        left: 400px;
        padding: 60px;
        border: solid 1px #ddd;
        border-radius: 20px;
        background: #F0E68C;
        width: 10%;
    }

    .popup .show {
        visibility: visible;
        -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
        animation: fadeIn 1s
    }


    @-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
        from {opacity: 0;}
        to {opacity: 1;}
    }

    @keyframes fadeIn {
        from {opacity: 0;}
        to {opacity:1 ;}
    }
    </style>

    </head>

    <body>



    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="application.js"></script>
<div class="Boma"  style="width: 1000px; height: 600px;">
             <img src="Boma_1_2/F16_20170316141116392_0001.jpg" onclick="myFunction(event)" alt="Boma" style="width:1000px;height:600px;">
    <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup"> <button class="button">Menu</button> </span>
        </div>

    </body>

    </html>
```

Here is my application.js code:

```
function myFunction(e) {

       var x=e.pageX;   
       var y=e.pageY;   
       $("#myPopup").css({ left: x });
       $("#myPopup").css({ top: y });
       $("#myPopup").show();

    }

jQuery.getJSON("/getMyJSON", (data) => {
    console.log(data);
});

$(document).ready(function(){
$('button').on('click', function(){
    var veg= $('<button>vegetation</button>');
    $('.popuptext').find('.button').replaceWith(veg);

});
});
```

Comment: this is too broad and basically you're asking a random person to write your code for you and this code does not help anybody except you..

Comment: Try `$('.popuptext').find('.button').text('vegetation')` instead..

Comment: update your question with this fiddle i am not getting a popup when i click on image https://jsfiddle.net/dpc81kje/

Comment: updated..please check now

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/7pp67vef/ easier not to do loads of coding ;)

Comment: @Anuga you removed the popup in your solution. I want to see these buttons inside the popup.

Comment: Even better: https://jsfiddle.net/7pp67vef/3/

Comment: @Anuga Can you please fit this functionality inside my popup. Your example seems to do the job but i want the buttons inside a popup similar to mine because later I have to add more buttons in it dynamically. For example if vegetation is clicked there comes two more buttons which are the subclass (forest and plantation) of vegetation.